# Does Dovecot support UIDPLUS (RFC4315)?

Tags: linux, dovecot, maildir

I have Dovecot version `1.2.9-1ubuntu6.3` installed on my server (using Maildir+), and I was reading [an article](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2010/02/05/better-imap-in-outlook-2010.aspx) on Outlook 2010 that says that Outlook will purge messages immediately if the server supports UIDPLUS.

From my Googling, all I can find is a bunch of outdated mailing list messages of people asking questions. Does Dovecot support UIDPLUS for Maildir+/Maildir? Can it be added as an extension or is there some other way of adding this functionality? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just connect to your server and send it the CAPABILITY command and see if it returns UIDPLUS?

Comment: @Cedric Why don't you put that as an answer? It answered my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find out which capabilities your server has, you can simply connect to it and issue the CAPABILITY command. That should show you UIDPLUS if your server supports the extension.

Comment: Sure enough... `* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS MULTIAPPEND UNSELECT IDLE CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN` (UIDPLUS is in there!)